# Scrapy cookies not working when sending Proxy-Authorization header

Tags: cookies, proxy, scrapy

I'm using proxy like this:

```
request = Request(url="www.domain.com")    

in middleware:

request.meta['proxy'] = "http://2.2.2.2:8000"
user_pass = base64.encodestring('username:password')
request.headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + user_pass
```

And cookies like this:

```
request = Request(url="www.domain.com", cookies={'preferences': 'ps=www2'})
```

When I using cookies and proxy separately all works fine, but when I'm trying to combine both cookies and proxy in one request:

```
request = Request(url="www.domain.com", cookies={'preferences': 'ps=www2'})

in middleware:

request.meta['proxy'] = "http://2.2.2.2:8000"
user_pass = base64.encodestring('username:password')
request.headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + user_pass
```

cookies are just not sent to the server.

My suggestion: something wrong with sending header for proxy authorization. It's just cutting off cookies.

Comment: Did you find solution? It only happens when we use `Proxy-Authorization` header in Scrapy, the cookies are not sent to server :(

Answer (score 0):

change

```
request.headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + user_pass
```

to

```
request.headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + user_pass.strip()
```